# Linux Mint 14 issues with WiFi connectivity

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, internet, connection, linux-mint

For the past month and a half or so I've been trying rid myself of my Windows dependency. I have tried Fedora, Ubuntu, and now Linux Mint. Everything works great except for WiFi.

I install the distro and everything works great for about two days, no issues at all.

Then my internet connection starts to fail, every single time. It will connect to the internet, then lose connectivity and not be able to reconnect at all. I'll do a restart, and the internet connection will come back, only to be lost again after fifteen minutes. I've looked into this extensively, and I believe it has something to do with the drivers for my card, it is a RealTek type card.

I've tried doing the solution I've found for similar problems on my own but I've always ended up doing more harm than good. I think the best way to do this would be to use the Windows driver for the card in Linux. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your post by mentioning "Wifi connection" since you did not mention it anywhere other than in your `tags`.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that installing windows driver is the best solution. Your device will perform at its best when the driver is developed for linux. It can be community developed or manufacturer made and it is just the matter of installing it. Can you post output of this command from `terminal`? `sudo lspci -v | grep -i wireless` and mention your laptop/PC model.

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a way (if not more than this one) to use Windows drivers on Linux.

One way is as described:

Step1: Open Synaptics (or any package manager capable of doing so)
Step2: Select, download and install `ndiswrapper-utils`.
Step3: Run it and enjoy your Windows drivers on Linux.

source (applicable not only to ubuntu): [Link](http://techtips.salon.com/convert-windows-drivers-linux-11847.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

Install the rtl8192-all deb
http://www.filewatcher.com/d/Debian/all/non-free/kernel/firmware-realtek_0.36_all.deb.202064.html

Use network manager and choose your wifi network and then click forget it

Now connect to your network manually by clicking the Connect to a hidden network button at the bottom of your window

My connection speed has increased and no connection losses yet!